# DNS resolution failing inside docker container when host network changes without rebooting device

Tags: docker, dns, resolve, nameservers, dnsmasq

#### Expected behavior

DNS resolution failing inside docker container when host network changes ( network1-192.168.1.*, network2-192.168.2.* ) without rebooting device
docker container running on bridge network

#### Actual behavior

DNS resolution should be successful in case of host network changes

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

1. Create network container (lets say.. "abc_network.ctr") without specifying network_mode as it takes bridge by default (and it used docker's embedded nameserver inside docker container)
2. Create another container (xyz.ctr) whose network mode will be "container" ("abc_network.ctr")
3. /etc/resolv.conf from inside the xyz.ctr container. which is able to resolve nameserver

```
    root@d3e0dc71f370:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
    nameserver 127.0.0.11
    options ndots:0
```

4. /etc/resolv.conf from host.. which is also able to resolve nameserver

```
    root@RP4-2711-c03112-1xb0e6f3b8:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
    # This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
    #
    # This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
    # all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
    #
    # Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
    # symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
    # replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
    #
    # See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
    # operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
    
    nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

5. Change network subnet of the machine (remove LAN cable and connect to another subnet network1 -> network2) without reboot.
6. And try to resolve nameserver inside docker container using following commands:

- docker exec -it xyz.ctr bash
- apt-get update
  result-

```
    root@d3e0dc71f370:~# apt-get update
    Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
      Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
    Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                  
      Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
    Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
      Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
    Reading package lists... Done    
    W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
    W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
    W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
    W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

- dig output

```
     root@15c396b06f57:~# dig
    
    ; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u5-Debian <<>>
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

7. /etc/resolve.conf from host machine which is able to resolve nameserver

```
    # This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
    #
    # This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
    # all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
    #
    # Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
    # symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
    # replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
    #
    # See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
    # operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
    
    nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

8. apt-get working on host and dig command shows NO ERROR

**Output of `docker version`:**

```
    Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289
```

**Output of `docker info`:**

```
    root@RP4-2711-c03112-1xb0e6f3b8:~# docker info
    Client:
     Context:    default
     Debug Mode: false
     Plugins:
      app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
      buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)
    
    Server:
     Containers: 22
      Running: 18
      Paused: 0
      Stopped: 4
     Images: 98
     Server Version: 20.10.6
     Storage Driver: overlay2
      Backing Filesystem: extfs
      Supports d_type: true
      Native Overlay Diff: true
      userxattr: false
     Logging Driver: json-file
     Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
     Cgroup Version: 1
     Plugins:
      Volume: local
      Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
      Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
     Swarm: inactive
     Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
     Default Runtime: runc
     Init Binary: docker-init
     containerd version: 05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
     runc version: 12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
     init version: de40ad0
     Security Options:
      seccomp
       Profile: default
     Kernel Version: 5.10.17-v7l+
     Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
     OSType: linux
     Architecture: armv7l
     CPUs: 4
     Total Memory: 3.44GiB
     Name: RP4-2711-c03112-1xb0e6f3b8
     ID: C66C:3DAT:6DLH:PHJA:JR2N:KURB:PTMQ:BHUP:XRIH:FE3H:VSEZ:B7K3
     Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
     Debug Mode: false
     Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
     Labels:
     Experimental: false
     Insecure Registries:
      127.0.0.0/8
     Live Restore Enabled: false
     Default Address Pools:
       Base: 172.128.0.1/10, Size: 16
    
    WARNING: No memory limit support
    WARNING: No swap limit support
    WARNING: No kernel memory TCP limit support
    WARNING: No oom kill disable support
```

**Additional environment details (AWS, VirtualBox, physical, etc.)**

Device- Raspberry Pi-4B, Intel NUC (This is not an environment specific issue)